# Get all the indexes from the array on matching the condition

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have int array which is returned from preparedStatement as below:

```
int[] updateResultArray = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
```

as per my understanding, above returned array will contains the count of rows get affected on each update query which is added on that batch.
so, the result will be something like [0,2,1,0,0,1,2], here i want to fetch only the index which has the value greater than zero.
My expected result should return the index 1,2,5,6. I know we can convert it to list and do the below code:

```
int[] indexes =
                    IntStream.range(0, names.size())
                             .filter(i -> names.get(i)>0)
                             .toArray();
```

But is there any other way, without this conversion. Can anyone please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert the array to List to do this operation, all you can do is:

```
int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, updateResultArray.length)
        .filter(i -> updateResultArray[i] > 0)
        .toArray();
```